# Issues with an interaction between ajax and php?

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, forms, post

I'm developing a form that submits several user inputs to a database via post and handled by php. In order to do so, I'm using ajax (I know jquery is sometimes easier, but I'd prefer to get a grasp on ajax first).

However, it is not working properly - namely that it doesn't work at all. I know for a fact that the php file works fine when the form isn't passed through ajax.

Here's what I have right now - the form itself:

```
<table border="0" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="5">
                <th colspan="2" align="center">Check Out</th>
                <form name="checkOut" method="post" onSubmit="return(validate(this))" action=""> 
                    <tr><td>Territory Number</td><td><input type="text" name="numberOut" tabindex="1" maxlength="3" size="3" /></td>
                    </tr><tr><td>First Name of Publisher</td><td><input type="text" onKeyUp="showHint(this.value)" name="fName" tabindex="2" maxlength="15"/></td>
                    </tr><tr><td>Last Name of Publisher</td><td><input type="text" onKeyUp="showHint_l(this.value)" name="lName" tabindex="3" maxlength="15" /></td>
                    </tr><tr><td><input type ="checkbox" name="specialC" tabindex="4" value="Yes"/> Special Campaign</td>
                    </tr><tr><td><input type="button" onClick="clearForm()" value="Reset" /></td><td><input type="submit" value="Check Out" /></td>
                </form>
                <p>Suggestions: <span id="txtHint"></span></p>
            </table>
```

The javascript/ajax handler function:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        function validate(form)
        {
            fail = validateTerrNum(document.checkOut.numberOut.value);
            fail += validateFirstName(document.checkOut.fName.value);
            fail += validateLastName(document.checkOut.lName.value);
            if (fail == "")
            {
                //Begin preparing values for submission to server
                var params = "numberOut="+document.getElementsByName("numberOut")[0].value;
                    params+="?fName="+document.getElementsByName("fName")[0].value;
                    params+="?lName="+document.getElementsByName("lName")[0].value;
                var isSc = document.getelementsByName("specialC")[0].checked;
                if(isSc)
                {
                    params+="?specialC=Yes";
                }

                //Send those values to the server
                checkOut(params);
                return true;            
            }           
            else 
            {
                alert(fail);
                return false;
            }
        }
    </script>
```

And finally the ajax function via post:

```
function checkOut(params)
{
var urlString = params;
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
{// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
    xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
}
else
{// code for IE6, IE5
    xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
}

xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
{
    if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
    document.getElementById("test").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText; 
    }
}
//Setup for post submission 
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-length", params.length);
xmlhttp.open("POST","checkOut.php",true);
xmlhttp.send(urlString);
}
```

My suspicion is that I'm not submitting the post request correctly. I've had other ajax functions work with this form correctly, but it was through get - and I do want to use post because it is changing data in the database.

If anyone has some insight on this, it would be appreciated.

Edit: New Form with general button:

```
<table border="0" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="5">
                <th colspan="2" align="center">Check Out</th>
                <form name="checkOut" method="post" action=""> 
                    <tr><td>Territory Number</td><td><input type="text" name="numberOut" tabindex="1" maxlength="3" size="3" /></td>
                    </tr><tr><td>First Name of Publisher</td><td><input type="text" onKeyUp="showHint(this.value)" name="fName" tabindex="2" maxlength="15"/></td>
                    </tr><tr><td>Last Name of Publisher</td><td><input type="text" onKeyUp="showHint_l(this.value)" name="lName" tabindex="3" maxlength="15" /></td>
                    </tr><tr><td><input type ="checkbox" name="specialC" tabindex="4" value="Yes"/> Special Campaign</td>
                    </tr><tr><td><input type="button" onClick="clearForm()" value="Reset" /></td><td><input type="button" onClick="return(validate(this))" value="Check Out"/></td>
                </form>
                <p>Suggestions: <span id="txtHint"></span></p>
            </table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to cancel the form submit if you're posting the data via ajax, otherwise the form will submit and that may cancel your ajax request.

Also you have to call `setRequestHeader` after you call `open`

Comment: Can you expand on that, I don't quite understand what you're saying? Are you essentially saying that instead of submitting the form, create a button that triggers the function instead with the available input?

Comment: @Mlagma if you click the submit button on a form the form will submit, loading a new page which will cancel any action that was being performed on the previous page, e.g. ajax. So if your posting your data via ajax you should prevent the form itself from posting.

Comment: Makes sense. So the javascript will still be able to grab the value via DOM even without a form submission? Other than that, though, the functions look fine?

Comment: @Mlagma yes you can use javascript to get the value of the form fields without the form submitting.

Comment: I just tried switching it from submit to a general button; it still didn't work.

Comment: @Mlagma did you bind a click handler to the button to call the ajax

Comment: Yes, I just edited my question above with the new form. Jsbin says I'm missing a semicolon on line 19 of my ajax function, but I don't see where.

Comment: I just flipped the order of the calls, and it unfortunately didn't work.

Comment: @Mlagma do you get any errors, doesn't work is not very descriptive.

Comment: Unfortunately, there aren't any errors to share. The issue boiled down to two things. My original code had the readystate handlers, .open, and .send in the onreadystate change function, and the url did used ? instead of &. Thanks for the help.